# How to add infowindow to a cluster marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

here is my reformulated question.

I'm dressing a random array of points to cluster them via markerclusterer.js.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.5 + (Math.random()/200), -73.60 -(Math.random()/20)),
        map: map,
        title: i.toString()
      });

}
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,Markers,mcOptions);
```

This is working well and now here is the problem.

I want to make that cluster to give me an infowindow or any other better alternative. 
So I changed the dom listener in markerclusterer.js 'click' event to 'dblclick' event. So my cluster will zoom with dblclick and not a single click, since I want that single click event to triger my infowindow with the clustered markers in a simple list. (if I can trigger the infowindow and gather the clustered marker info I can manage to display a list.)

I have made a new dom listener into markerclusterer.js :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function (e) {
    cMouseDownInCluster = false;
    if (!cDraggingMapByCluster) {
        var theBounds;
        var mz;
        var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();
        /**
         * This event is fired when a cluster marker is clicked.
         * @name MarkerClusterer#click
         * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that was clicked.
         * @event
         */
        google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
        google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "clusterclick", cClusterIcon.cluster_); // deprecated name


        // Prevent event propagation to the map:
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});
```

This is only a copy of the original without the "zoom" behavior.

EDIT:: Test

I've tested with console.log(mc.getMarkers()); to see if the markers were identified and it returned me [Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi, Bi]. So now I'm with the problem that I don't know what to do with that Bi thing.

Bi is a constructor containing all my info I need. So I can do what I want with it.

Now I need to check how if I zoom to the next cluster and I click on it... It gives me the 10 Bi again. I need to know how to get only the X of them that are managed into that new cluster.

Update: I can open the infowindow now. It is not at the good place but I can open it.

Update (7:00 pm): I have my infowindow working, but I can open an unlimited amount of it.

here is the code

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function (e) {
  cMouseDownInCluster = false;
  if (!cDraggingMapByCluster) {
      var theBounds;
      var mz;
      var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();
      var Mrk_cluster = mc.getMarkers();


      /**
       * This event is fired when a cluster marker is clicked.
       * @name MarkerClusterer#click
       * @param {Cluster} c The cluster that was clicked.
       * @event
       */
      google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
      google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "clusterclick", cClusterIcon.cluster_); // deprecated name
      //test infowindow
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+'<p>Test</p>' +'</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Mrk_cluster[0].position.lat(),Mrk_cluster[0].position.lng())
        });

          infowindow.open(map);



      console.log(mc.getMarkers());

      // Prevent event propagation to the map:
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
  }
```

});
So I'm trying to find a trigger that will stop that behavior.